# How would an IACRA suspension affect future applications?

Tags: faa, faa-approval

An [interesting question over on the new UAV.SE site](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-it-possible-to-get-a-faa-part-107-drone-license-if-one-has-had-a-pilot-licens) asks

> Is it possible to get a FAA Part 107 drone license if one has had a pilot license revoked or suspended?

The answer appears to be that it's not immediately fatal to the application (they would undoubtedly warn you not to bother if you've had a suspension or revocation), but they do ask about it.

In general, how does an IACRA suspension and/or revocation affect future applications of any type?